# What widget(s) to use for non-modal editing?

Tags: flutter

I want my users to input text values in-place, without buttons 'OK' and 'Cancel', so that the values get stored to the database right after they are entered.

I also want to show a nice message if the saving failed because of bad internet connection or some other issue.

What combination of widgets would be most suitable for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put together a widget library [self_storing_input](https://pub.dev/packages/self_storing_input).

To get the entered value loaded/stored from/to a database, you need to provide a 'dataKey' and a 'saver' to the widget. 'saver' is an object that implements sync method 'validate' and async methods 'save' and 'load'.

Check [the demo](https://self_storing_input.codemagic.app) to see how it works.